# How can I connect Ubuntu 14.04 to my wireless printer canon mp620

Tags: printing, canon

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS in VirtualBox.  Windows 7 is the host. I can get on the web just fine.  I can ping my wireless printer just fine.  I can login to my printer's administrative web site just fine.  When I add the printer to CUPS and try to print to it I get the message that the printer isn't responding.  Any suggestions on how to get it working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Find IP

Make sure the wireless printer is connected in same network segment as your computer
Use nmap or zenmap to find the IP of the printer
I used 
`nmap -T4 -F 192.168.1.1-254`
and got output as 

`Nmap scan report for new-host-2.home (192.168.1.8)
Host is up (0.054s latency).
Not shown: 98 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
515/tcp open  printer`

Look for the `printer` serviec with state `open` and then find the corresponding IP, and use in next step.

Add printer

Then launch printers -> New -> Enter URI (I entered http://192.168.1.8) -> Click Forward -> "Select printer from database" radio option -> Canon on list -> click Forward -> Select from the Model -> click Forward -> give a short name and description -> Click Apply

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings, Printers, add new printer, click on yours, wait, click "add", wait, you're done!
Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

First, it's a good idea to give your printer a static IP. I have done so in my router settings.
Then, go to settings, printers, add, and then select network printer and then "find network printer" and type the printer IP and search! Then your printer should pop up.

Hope this helps...!

The syntax for the printer IP is to put **http://** before the numbers of the address.

The "Enter Device URI" option also works with this.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting Network Printers in 10 Simple Steps

1. Go to dash
2. Type Printers
3. Click on the printer icon
4. Click add (+)
5. Click "Network Printer"s and select printer (you may have to wait
   a minute for it to load)
6. Click on your Printers title
7. Click "Forward"
8. Click Select for the Printers Company (choose recommend if you
   don't know)
9. Choose Model (choose recommend if you don't know)
   10.Choose the Number of Input Trays
10. Choose The Printers Name
11. Print Test Page

Comment: I have an issue here, any idea why step 5, ubuntu just keep on waiting for very long time (around an hour) still haven't finish loading? any possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to print to my wireless networked HP 4635 on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Give the printer a static IP in its settings on the front panel.
2. Install HPLIP.
3. Open System Settings ( Click gear icon or use Dash ). Click Printers.
4. Click Add at top left.
5. Click Network Printer.
6. Click AppSocket/HP JetDirect.
7. Enter the static IP address in the "Host" field, click Forward.
8. In the Choose Driver dialog, select manufacturer HP, click Forward.
9. Select Office Jet 4635 E-all-in-one in the Models box
10. Select the recommended driver in the Drivers box, in my case, hpcups 3.16.5.
11. Click any installable options that are installed, in my case, Duplexer. Click Forward.
12. Enter your desired name, description, and location, click Apply.
13. Print a test page if desired. Click OK.
14. If desired, right-click on it and set as default printer.

I also had luck with changing the "Device URI" to "http://10.0.0.58", the static IP for the printer.